# Should I be able to escape unscathed?

Tags: xcom-2

I have no experience with previous XCOM games but am playing on veteran as I enjoy a challenge. Is it feasible or normal to take damage to more than 50% of squad or be losing squad members every mission early on? This does not seem sustainable. My concern would be running out of supplies and always churning through rookies before getting squad members promoted deep into the game.

Comment: XCOM is notoriously difficult, I wouldn't recommend Veteran for a first timer. I'm a bit anal about loosing people so I would replay missions by reloading a previous save, later in the game though this got way to frequent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Squadmembers getting injured is part of the game. In fact, it is often hard to avoid. You will often encounter situations in which you simply can't do much to avoid taking a hit or two. It's not a problem as long as you have enough soldiers to rotate so you can always field a full team.

Also losing a low-level soldier is not that much of a setback. A new soldier is just 25§. The black-market value of your loot alone is often worth the recruitment price of a few new rookies.

But what can really hurt is losing a high-level soldier. As you progress in the game, the game-balance assumes that your team is leveled appropriately. Most late-game enemies have defense bonuses which counter the aim advantage of high-level soldiers so your hit percentage keeps about the same throughout the game. Also, technology alone won't be enough to counter many of the nasty tricks some late-game enemies have up their sleeves. You will need the overpowered abilities only high-level soldiers have.

This means that later in the game it will become practically impossible to keep building up new rookies (the rebel HQ sometimes allows you to hire some high-level soldiers, though... for a price). Losing a captain or higher in the mid-game can be a drastic setback, and losing multiple of your best soldiers at once often leaves you no option than to load an older savegame.

Comment: Thanks, after playing through some more I realized dropping the difficulty a notch is worth it for a first round. I was losing 1 and having the rest gravely injured (or worse) each mission. Thanks for the later game insight.

Comment: Would help to point out that this is why you want to rotate soldiers even without injuries, rather than always fielding all your best soldiers. Then, if a colonel dies in the late game, you can bring in a sergeant to start leveling up, rather than a rookie.

Comment: I always try to have at least 1 high level spare for each soldier class in an XCOM game, so that I'm not screwed if I lose a colonel level soldier.

Answer (score 1):

Deaths should be rare. On average you should lose less than one soldier between supply drops, or things can get tough in the long run. I have found the ideal roster to have three of each class, and you should cycle them to gain even experience for them so that if your Major grenadier gets wounded, the next best one should be Captain or at least Lieutenant.

Having more than 3 per class makes training them to Colonel rank too slow, and having just two per class is too risky because a pair of same class soldiers can easily be wounded at the same time.

In the first few missions you should consider taking a rookie with the rest of the folks even if you have 4 non-rookies available for the mission, just so you have more than 4 squaddies or better to maximize the chance to avoid having rookies in the first retaliation mission. But when GTS starts producing squaddies, you no longer should need to take rookies to missions.

When the average rank among your troops is at least somewhere between Corporal and Sergeant, try to buy replacement soldiers from resistance HQ or Black Market instead recruiting a rookie when you lose one, because they will have sufficiently high rank and this won't set you back your plans to get as many Colonels as possible. Sometimes you might have to wait for a supply drop or two until the correct class becomes available.

Getting multiple soldiers wounded constantly is also bad. You should have a flawless mission every now and then, and on average only have 1-2 soldiers wounded per mission, so you can always have enough battle-ready soldiers. Use engineer in AWC when necessary, or consider even using the HQ scanning bonus that makes healing faster in dire situations. Usually there is a few days wait between missions so you have a window to heal for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be losing soldiers. XCOM 2 is much stricter on this than XCOM 1 and the older X-Com games. In X-Com, troops were definitely disposable.

The reason is that there's no room to train your troops. Tough aliens come at you fast, and the Avatar counter forces your hand. High level troops are vital to survival, more so than good equipment. The game tracks the number of corporals you have and how early you get them - that's how important they are. You simply don't have the time to spare cycling between wounded lieutenants.

Try to minimize not just deaths, but shots fired at you. In XCOM 2, the best offense is a good defense. Your first few missions should all be Flawless, no wounds; ideally not a single shot fired at your units. Use flashbangs liberally; they make up over half my grenade arsenal. Get used to flanking, elevation and high cover.